# SocketIO transferring data in bursts rather than continuously

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, socket.io, flask-socketio

I have a program where the backend is written in `Python`, the frontend is written in `React/Electron` and I use websockets, specifically `Socket.IO` to communicate between the two (I use `Flask-SocketIO` in the backend).

I'd like to continuously transfer small amounts of data a few times a second (I'm aiming for 10 times a second) but on the receiving end of the browser the data comes in weird bursts:

```
data                        length      time
42["TRANSFER_DATA",250]     35          18:13:42.253
42["TRANSFER_DATA",253]     35          18:13:42.255
42["TRANSFER_DATA",259]     35          18:13:42.258
42["TRANSFER_DATA",265]     35          18:13:42.553
42["TRANSFER_DATA",270]     35          18:13:42.556
42["TRANSFER_DATA",276]     35          18:13:42.557
42["TRANSFER_DATA",281]     35          18:13:42.854
42["TRANSFER_DATA",287]     35          18:13:42.855
42["TRANSFER_DATA",292]     35          18:13:42.857
42["TRANSFER_DATA",298]     35          18:13:43.156
42["TRANSFER_DATA",303]     35          18:13:43.157
42["TRANSFER_DATA",309]     35          18:13:43.160
```

*Taken from the dev tools logs*

You can see that instead of coming in continuously (every 100ms) they come in 3 bursts every 300ms.
I have tested if it's the backend freezing up and can confirm that it is not, the issue is probably somewhere in Socket.IO itself.

*Very simplified* backend code:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
sio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins="*")

def send_single(data, event_name, jsonify=False):
    if jsonify:
        data = json.dumps(data)
    sio.emit(event_name, data, json=jsonify)

def main_loop():
    while True: # This code is really simplified I don't actually do while True loops in the code itself
        data = get_this_data_from_somewhere()
        send_single(data, "TRANSFER_DATA")
        time.sleep(0.1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    thread = threading.Thread(target=main_loop)
    thread.start()
    sio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=58989)
```

*Very simplified* frontend code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const socketURL = "http://127.0.0.1:58989";

class App extends Component {
    state = {value: 0};
    async initSocket(){
        const socket = io(socketURL);
        this.setState({socket});
        await socket.on('connect', async () => {
            console.log("SocketIO connection established");
        });
    };

    setupListeners = () => {
        this.state.socket.on('TRANSFER_DATA', (data) => {
            this.setState({value: data});
        });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.initSocket().then(this.setupListeners);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <React.Fragment>
                <span>{this.state.value}</span>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

**EDIT:**
I have tried to completely get rid of using `Flask` to see if it is a Flask related issue and after switching to `Gevent` and `python-socketio` the issue remains.

I also did some logging of the SocketIO server and it seems to be emitting correctly with 100ms intervals

```
2019-12-10 21:15:15,710  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:15,811  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:15,911  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,013  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,114  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,214  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,315  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,415  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
2019-12-10 21:15:16,516  INFO     emitting event "TRANSFER_DATA" to all [/]
```

Comment: Can you fire up Wireshark or some other packet sniffer and see if those Web Socket frames are being sent in a single packet?  I suspect Nagle is messing with you.

Comment: @Brad I have never worked with Wireshark but I believe they are being sent separately [Image link](https://imgur.com/emYI4Yy)

Comment: Might be some throttling on the browser end then.  Do the timings look right to you on the TCP packets?

Comment: @Brad In Wireshark they still seem to be all sent three times within 300ms.

Comment: Ok, in that case, then now you know the problem is on the server end.  :-)  Perhaps this is some Python Socket.IO or Flask optimization.

Comment: @Tornith you have omitted some important details. I need to know if you are using eventlet or gevent along with Flask-SocketIO, and if you are, wether you have monkey patched the standard library or not.

Comment: @Miguel I'm using `gevent` atm and i didn't monkey patch the standard library (I'm assuming the issue might be there?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Miguel's response I realized that I forgot to monkey patch the standard library and that seem to have done the trick!

```
from gevent import monkey
monkey.patch_all()
```